# How do I specify column family in RocksDB using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, rocksdb

I want to read a RocksDB file. I get an error:

```
rocksdb.errors.InvalidArgument: b'Invalid argument: Column families not opened: col11, col10, col9, col8, col7, col6, col5, col4, col3, col2, col1, col0'
```

So, I googled and specified the column family in my code while accessing the database:

```
column_families = {}
column_families[b"col1"] = rocksdb.ColumnFamilyOptions()


db_path = "<path to the database>"
db = rocksdb.DB(db_path, rocksdb.Options(create_if_missing=False), column_families = column_families)
```

I still receive the same error even though I provided the columns mentioned in the error message.

How do I iterate over the rows from this database?

Answer (score 0):

Specifying all the columns from the error message worked.

```
column_families = {}
columns = ["col9", "col8", "col7", "col6", "col5", "col4", "col3", "col2", "col1", "col11", "col0", "col10"]
for column in columns:
    column_families[bytes("{}".format(column), encoding='utf-8')] = rocksdb.ColumnFamilyOptions()
```